# How do Iupdate a JComponent when it was created in the constructor?

Tags: java, swing

So, I have a constructor below, I am new to Java so it's probably longer than it should be, but what it basically does is create a window that has a Jlist, a play button, and a pause button. In the Jlist will be names of music files. On first startup the program should hopefully ask for the directory of where the music is stored.

My problem is I want to give the user the choice, to select a new directory but I do not know how I would update my Jlist that is on the Jpanel, as all that stuff was determined in the constructor. My only Idea would be to redraw the entire Jframe,panel and components but that seems like a bad idea.
Below my Constructor I posted what I was attempting to do but that does not work.

```
Player(){
        preferences = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
        ID = "Preferred Directory";
        preferences.get(ID,"");
        features = new PlayerFeatures();
        Ispaused = false;
        DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class,null);
        fileExplorer = new JFileChooser();
        fileExplorer.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        if(preferences.get(ID,"").equals("")){
            int returnVal = fileExplorer.showOpenDialog(chooseDirectory);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                directory = fileExplorer.getCurrentDirectory();
                preferences.put(ID,directory.toString());
            }

        }

        directory = new File(preferences.get(ID,""));
        //get resource grabs things, with get resource we can grab things that are sitting in side the class folder.
        //directory = new File("C:\\Users\\Jude\\Documents\\musicalChairs\\src");

        List<String> list = makePlayList(directory);
        System.out.println(list);
        songs = new String[list.size()];
        songs = list.toArray(songs);
        playList = new JList(songs);
        playList.addMouseListener(new listMouseListener());
        playList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        playList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
        playList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
        frame = new JFrame();
        panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelBottom,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        play = new JButton();
        play.addActionListener(new playListener());
        pause = new JButton();
        pause.addActionListener(new pauseListener());
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(playList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        panelTop.add(scrollPane);
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        chooseDirectory = new JMenuItem("Select Music Folder",KeyEvent.VK_S);
        chooseDirectory.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1,ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        chooseDirectory.addActionListener(new chooseDirectoryListener());
        menu.add(chooseDirectory);
        menuBar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        try{
            Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Play24.gif"));
            Image pauseImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Pause16.gif"));
            play.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            pause.setIcon(new ImageIcon(pauseImg));
            Dimension buttonDimensions = new Dimension(25,26);
            play.setPreferredSize(buttonDimensions);
            pause.setPreferredSize(buttonDimensions);


        }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
            System.out.println("No input exist");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error while reading");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }


        features.songURL = Player.class.getResource(songs[0]);
        panelBottom.add(play);
        panelBottom.add(pause);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST,panelTop);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,panelBottom);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
class chooseDirectoryListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int returnVal = fileExplorer.showOpenDialog(chooseDirectory);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                directory = fileExplorer.getCurrentDirectory();
                preferences.put(ID,directory.toString());
                List<String> list = makePlayList(directory);
                songs = new String[list.size()];
                songs = list.toArray(songs);
                playList = new JList(songs);
                playList.addMouseListener(new listMouseListener());
                playList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                playList.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
                playList.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
                scrollPane = new JScrollPane(playList);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                panelTop.add(scrollPane);
                System.out.println("why");
                panelTop.revalidate();
                panelTop.repaint();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you save a reference to the JList and update the data source using JList.setListData(Object[] data) method?

Comment: @ZacharyThompson Hmm, I am trying that right now but now I have discovered that in my listener class, the directory reference variable is not changing when I select a new one
Edit: Actually It's just the file explorer acting strangely, the list will update on restart but not live.

Comment: Not sure I'm following - As you are updating the component you will need to ensure that it gets repainted. If you want this handled for you I believe you can use a ListModel to handle changes and everything is more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve what you are wanting to do, use a [DefaultListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). Something like this **should** work, although untested.

```
private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel;

public Constructor () {
    JList playlist = new JList(model);
    panelTop.add(playlist);
    ...
}

public void addItem (String item) {
    model.add(0, item);
}

public void removeItem (String item) {
    model.remove(model.indexOf(item));
}

public void clearItems () {
    model.clear();
}
```

Below is a relatively hasty attempt to test if the list would update after removing and adding an item. It has been tested as does perform as expected.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new 

DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
model.add(0, "Item 0");
model.add(1, "Item 1");

JList list = new JList(model);

frame.add(panel);
panel.add(list);

frame.setVisible(true);

model.remove(0);
model.add(1, "Item 234");
```

Comment: Yes this worked!

So for my sake of understanding,  is a model, pretty much my connection to the JList itself, and gives me easier/direct access to manipulating the elements of the JList?

Comment: Glad it worked. You can think of it like that as it does a good job of providing an interface to modify the elements of the Jlist. A model simply defines how the J Component, JList in this case, gets each element.